# Recursive function causing webpage to go completely blank

Tags: php, menu, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print a menu with a recursive function. I used examples of code from these questions:

[Echo menu tree with recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782810/echo-menu-tree-with-recursive-function)

[Create an multidimensional array from a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503151/create-an-multidimensional-array-from-a-database-table)

The code seems right to me and is syntactically correct, but I get a blank page as a result. There are no errors, but the HTML following this php isn't showing up either. Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_database)
or die ("Couldn't connect to server: ".mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)
    or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());

function menuPrint($categories, $parent = 'root', $level = 0)
{
    $menuList = '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $index => $category)
    {
      if($category['Parent'] == $parent)
      {
        $menuList .= '<li id="'.$category['ID'].'" class="tier'.$level.'">'.$category['Name'];
        $check = $this->menuPrint($categories, $category['ID'], $level+1);
        if($check != '<ul></ul>')
            $menuList .= $check;
        $menuList .= '</li>';
      }
    }
    return $menuList . '</ul>';
}

$catgories = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categories[] = array(
        'ID' => $row['categoryId'],
        'Name' => $row['categoryName'],
        'Parent' => $row['parentCategory'],
        'Disabled' => $row['disabled']
    );
}
$menu = $this->menuPrint($categories);
echo $menu;

mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Do you know where the problem is localized to? Does the script complete it's execution with $menu being blank? What happens if you simply remove the recursive call to `menuPrint()`, does it work then? Also, you call the method: `$this->menuPrint(...)` - is this in an object? If so, then what is the code outside of the function in? if not, why do you use `$this`?

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($categories)`? Also, you misspelled the variable `$catgories` in one place, is that mistake in the original code?

Comment: Jakerella - while trying to gather the answers to all your questions, I solved the issue! The `$this->` was causing the problem. I originally modified a bit of code from one of the articles that I posted above, but didn't realize I had removed the method that was created. No wonder the code was blowing up. There was no method to call. I feel dumb. But I'm really glad that your questions led to the answer. Thank you! Is there a way to give you credit for that?

Comment: Barmar - Thank you! I didn't see that misspelling and it surely helped answering the problem. An extra pair of eyes is so helpful when you have been staring at the same bit of code for so long.